# Mysql self join with aggregate is slow and optimized differently than intended

Tags: mysql

I've a query which performs slow (~20s) and after doing a fair amount of reading and digging I can't seem to figure out a solution.

The query is:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   tire_transaction AS t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT license_plate, 
                          Max(transaction_date) AS `last_checkin` 
                   FROM   tire_transaction 
                   GROUP  BY license_plate) AS t2 
               ON t1.license_plate = t2.license_plate 
                  AND t1.transaction_date = t2.last_checkin 
WHERE  ( t1.client_id = '1' ) 
       AND ( t1.deleted = 0 )
```

The result is:

```
id  select_type  table             type    possible_keys                                                              key                  key_len  ref                                 rows  filtered  Extra        
 1  PRIMARY      <derived2>        ALL     (NULL)                                                                     (NULL)               (NULL)   (NULL)                             69121    100.00               
 1  PRIMARY      t1                ref     client_id,license_plate,tire_transaction_date,deleted,license__trans_date  license__trans_date  67       t2.last_checkin,t2.license_plate       1    100.00  Using where  
 2  DERIVED      tire_transaction  index   (NULL)                                                                     license_plate        63       (NULL)                            366423    100.00
```

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tire_transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `transaction_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_urgent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `license_plate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `license_plate_country` varchar(2) DEFAULT 'NL',
  `chassis_number` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_salutation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_postalcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_phone_alt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tire_type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `set_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rim_material` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `license_plate` (`license_plate`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `client_name` (`client_name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tire_transaction_entityId` (`entity_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tire_transaction_parentId` (`parent_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tire_transaction_date` (`transaction_date`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `license__trans_date` (`transaction_date`,`license_plate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=418618 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There are like 400K rows. Mysql is optimizing the query and rewriting the ON statement as a WHERE statement which I think is where the slowness comes from.

Any thoughts on this one? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain, what the query is supposed to do? It doesn't look reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your filters to the subquery. I'm not sure if that would return the same result. But according to the column names, it looks like it should.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   tire_transaction AS t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT license_plate, 
                          Max(transaction_date) AS `last_checkin` 
                   FROM   tire_transaction 
                   WHERE  ( t1.client_id = '1' )  -- line added
                     AND  ( t1.deleted = 0 )      -- line added
                   GROUP  BY license_plate) AS t2 
               ON t1.license_plate = t2.license_plate 
                  AND t1.transaction_date = t2.last_checkin 
WHERE  ( t1.client_id = '1' ) -- line can probably be deleted
       AND ( t1.deleted = 0 ) -- line can probably be deleted
```

You should also add an index on `(client_id, license_plate, transaction_date)`.

Comment: You should also add `deleted` to the composite index

Comment: Im not sure if those query are equivalent. You are removing rows before calculating the `MAX(date)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've assumed that `deleted` isn't very selective (most rows not deleted). But yes - `(client_id, deleted, license_plate, transaction_date)` would be a better index.

Comment: The queries are not equivalent. But depending on data, the result might be the same.

Comment: Great replies guys! This helped me solve the performance issue!

Answer (score 0):

One area where you might be able to improve your performance is the subquery which involves a `GROUP BY` aggregation (aliased as `t2`).  Consider adding a composite index on `license_plate` and `transaction_date`:

```
CREATE INDEX tire_idx on tire_transaction(license_plate, transaction_date);
```

If you peruse the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) on optimizing `GROUP BY` queries, the above index should allow MySQL to do the aggregation via a loose index scan.  If the above works, then you should see `Using index for group-by` in the `Extra` column of when you run `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I would also add `(license_plate, client_id, deleted)` index for the outter query.